# Splitting a RGB value up for an xml feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, regex, rgb

I have the following to generate an xml feed:

```
def export
  @borders = Border.order("display_order_position ASC").all
  require 'nokogiri'
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.dict {
      xml.key "colors"
      xml.array {
        @borders.each do |b|
        xml.dict{
          xml.key "type"
          xml.string b.border_type
          if b.border_type == "pattern"
            xml.key "image"
            xml.string b.pattern
          elsif b.border_type == "texture"
            xml.key "image"
            xml.string b.texture
          elsif b.border_type == "color"
            xml.key "r"
            xml.key "g"
            xml.key "b"
          end
        }
        end

      }
    }
  end
  puts builder.to_xml
end
```

For the colour option I have an rgb value like rgb(47, 69, 184) which I need to split into three separate values and I'm not sure how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're certain that your colour value will **always** be a string in the form "rgb(x, y, z)", then you can use this regex:

```
rgb\((\d+), *(\d+), *(\d+)\)
```

That is: the literal string `rgb(`, a group of digits `(\d+)` followed by a comma and possibly some whitespace `, *`, two more similar entries, and finally a closing bracket `\)`. Here's a Ruby demo:

```
color = "rgb(47, 69, 184)"
regex = /rgb\((\d+), *(\d+), *(\d+)\)/
result = regex.match(color)
p result[1] # "47"
p result[2] # "69"
p result[3] # "184"
```